# Sencha Architect - how to add dummy data

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I'm developing an app with Sencha Architectur. But I got a little question.
I got a nested-list, how can I add custom data, just for quick testing. Because I don't want to create a model and stores with an json-url.

Thanks

Comment: Dam'n. Found out what the problem was.

When I add an array-string in the data-field (in the configuration panel), after my input, I must click in the design / code canvas. I thought first that I couldn't add custom data, but it seems its a little bug in the Architect app.

Problem solved :)